# What is the attribute that defines the color alpha? XML fusioncharts

Tags: xml, charts, graphics, dataset, fusioncharts

I'm trying to make a graph in XML, it's all right, but it shows me at the beginning of the graph a "white" color, I would like to know what is the property that defines that

```
Dim strxml = ""
        strxml = strxml & "  <chart caption ='Control en la validación de AS BUILT' xAxisName='ESTADO DE GESTIÓN' yAxisName='Total' rotatevalues='0' valuefontcolor='ffffff' placeValuesInside='1' animation='1' showYAxisValues='1' formatNumberScale='0' labelDisplay='rotate' slantLabels='1' showLabels='1' > "
        strxml = strxml & "  <categories> "
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 2
            strxml = strxml & "      <category label='" & dt.Rows(i).Item("estado").ToString() & "'/>"
        Next
        strxml = strxml & "  </categories> "
        'strxml = strxml & "  <dataset color='fa5c05'>"
        strxml = strxml & " <dataset seriesname = 'RF AB' color='84500A'>"
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            strxml = strxml & " <set value='" & dt.Rows(i).Item("ab_rf") & "'/>"
        Next
        strxml = strxml & " </dataset>"
        strxml = strxml & " <dataset seriesname = 'FO CONST' >"
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            strxml = strxml & " <set value='" & dt.Rows(i).Item("const") & "'/>"
        Next
        strxml = strxml & " </dataset>"
        strxml = strxml & " <dataset seriesname = 'FO FUS. PE' >"
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            strxml = strxml & " <set value='" & dt.Rows(i).Item("fus_pe") & "'/>"
        Next
        strxml = strxml & " </dataset>"
        strxml = strxml & " <dataset seriesname = 'FO FUS. PI' >"
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            strxml = strxml & " <set value='" & dt.Rows(i).Item("fus_pi") & "'/>"
        Next
        strxml = strxml & " </dataset>"
        strxml = strxml & " <dataset seriesname = 'PI ACTA' >"
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            strxml = strxml & " <set value='" & dt.Rows(i).Item("acta") & "'/>"
        Next
        strxml = strxml & " </dataset>"
        strxml = strxml & " </chart> "

        Literal3.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChartHTML("../../FusionCharts/Charts/MSColumn2D.swf", "", strxml, "myNext", "900", "400", False, True, True)
```

it looks like this

[Image of graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXjR2.png)

I think the problem could be here

```
strxml = strxml & "  <chart caption ='Control en la validación de AS BUILT' xAxisName='ESTADO DE GESTIÓN' yAxisName='Total' rotatevalues='0' valuefontcolor='ffffff' placeValuesInside='1' animation='1' showYAxisValues='1' formatNumberScale='0' labelDisplay='rotate' slantLabels='1' showLabels='1' > "
```

Comment: you are using a deprecated version of FusionCharts, FusionCharts now renders in javascript, it does not use flash anymore, any way you can try alpha attribute at the data level or dataset level, here is an example

dataset level - <dataset seriesname = 'RF AB' color='84500A' alpha='10'>
data level - <set value='" & dt.Rows(i).Item("const") & "' alpha="50"/>

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED IT :D

I POST THE ANSWER:

I will give the answer for those who need it

need to add the parameter "plotGradientColor" with two single quotes

plotGradientColor=''

the result is:

[IMG OF GRAPHICS[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svCLV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svCLV.png)

that is for old version of fusioncharts.

For the new version you can use the new parameter:

"usePlotGradientColor": "0"

Good luck to you all